# Cascade dropdown for multi select fields

Tags: sharepoint-designer, 2013, jquery, dropdown, cascading

I have successfully implemented the [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/releases/view/81401) JQuery open source solution but unfortunately it doesn't seem to support multi select fields (I mean the ones where you can enable "allow multiple values"). Can you suggest another Library (possibily but unlikely free) that can achieve that result? Or, even better, is there any way to achieve that directly in Sharepoint (perhaps through Sharepoint Designer)? I find hard to believe that Sharepoint 2013 doesn't support that kind of feature yet.

FYI I am working with Sharepoint Foundation 2013 and Sharepoint Designer 2013.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would use the new REST services combined with select2.js

For starters how to use Lookupvalues and Rest/Jquery:

- http://www.sharepointalex.co.uk/index.php/2012/12/sharepoint-2013retrieving-the-lookup-value-of-user-fields-using-the-rest-api/
- http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/Applying-Filters-to-Lookup-Fields-with-the-SP2013-REST-API

For select2.js: http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

Surely its not that comfortable as spservices, but at least its possible.

Best of all: all free as in beer.

Answer (score -1):

Do you get Managed Metadata in Foundation?  If so have you considered using a multi-tier term set to achieve this requirement?