# Add auto complete to lookup field and allow multiple selections

Tags: lookup-column, multi-select, auto-populate

I'm trying to make a lookup field on a newform.aspx have auto complete **AND** allow multiple selections.  The following script works great **BUT** only allows one choice.  Does anyone know how to modify this script or have another one that will allow **automcomplete AND multiple selections**?

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/SiteAssets/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/SiteAssets/jquery.SPServices.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        document.getElementById('Column ID').title = 'Column Title';
        $().SPServices.SPAutocomplete({ 
            sourceList: "Source List Name",
            sourceColumn: "Source List Title Internal Name",
            columnName: "NewForm.aspx column Display Name",
            ignoreCase: true,
            numChars: 2,
            slideDownSpeed: 50,
            debug: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please check [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/253274/51122) answer. Maybe it will be helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I'm not looking for cascading and wouldn't know how to modify this.  Our lookup list has 40 items and more might be added so checkboxes tends make it cluttered.  I appreciate the response though!