# Multi-Select Cascading Dropdown in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, cascading, multi-select, cascading-dropdown

I am customizing a list in SharePoint via PowerApps.

My end goal is simple - I wish to have two multi-select dropdowns whereby the second dropdown would rely on the first dropdown.

As an example, My first dropdown would contain values for 'Countries' and my second dropdown would contain values for 'Languages' based on languages spoken in those countries, both allowing the user to multi-select options.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can follow these articles to create a Multi-Select Cascading Dropdown in SharePoint in SharePoint List.

[SharePoint Online: How to Implement Cascading Drop-down in 3 Steps?](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/01/sharepoint-online-cascading-drop-down-list-using-jquery.html)

[Cascade dropdown for multi select fields](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/208638/cascading-drop-down-in-sharepoint-online-for-multi-values)